# Shippo Webhook Order Details

Tags: shippo

One of the properties the Shippo webhook can return is the "Order" object, but none of my requests are populating this field, it's always null.

I've looked over the documentation regarding webhooks but it's pretty minimal.

Is there any information regarding what drives this field? We're using the Shopify Integration to pull our orders into Shippo.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to build? It sounds like you're trying to import orders from Shopify into Shippo,  in which case you can use the pre-built integration: https://support.goshippo.com/hc/en-us/articles/203723895-Which-stores-do-you-integrate-with-How-do-I-connect-my-store-

Comment: It sounds like OP is already using the Shopify integration. It's unclear to me what Order object/property you're referring to though? The Shippo webhooks never return an Order object. We offer webhooks for Transaction, Track and Batch. The Transaction object has a property called Order, which is the ID of the Order the Transaction is linked to (or null). It would be helpful if you can provide more details on your use case.

Comment: I think that's exactly what i was looking for.. i couldn't find anything in the documentation that stated it's purpose so I was curious what drove that property. 

We are using the shopify integration, the problem we're having is integrating with our fulfillment center and getting the shipping labels alongside the order line items sent over in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the problem had to do with a few variables.

- Using Test Mode to purchase a label will not update the Shopify Fulfillment deatils.
- The Webhook test was not including the order field, this makes sense as again test data does not appear to be included.
- It would appear that the webhooks would not fire off of a test transaction, which in retrospect makes sense since they included the test button.

Once I moved the carrier out of test mode and purchased a label everything seemed to flow as you would expect.